# How do you access a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created a multidimensional array to access each of the arrays I stored from a MySQL query, using this statement:

```
$new_array[$n][$row['MLocID']] = $row;
```

Below is the output from `print_r(get_defined_vars(), true)`:

```
[new_array] => Array
    (
    [0] => Array
         (
         [226] => Array
                 (
                  [MLocID] => 226
                  [MemberID] => 2
                  [SupBusName] => Albertsons
```

I did this to store the results in arrays, so I can access them later on the same PHP page. I thought it would work better the way I did it, but now I think I made it more confusing to access. That is the first issue. I can't figure out how to get the data? I thought it was like this:

```
$new_array[0][$row[0]];
```

But it does not work. I tried different variations, but none worked for me. The second issue is, I don't know if I did more harm by putting my results in arrays. Is it more logical to do it the way I did, or is it better to do separate queries by using the `'MLocID'` number to access the data, for the 5 results I will have on each page?

Comment: In what language?  It looks like PHP, but every language is different.  Please tag the correct language.

Comment: Typically, to access the rows of a result set, you'll use something like `foreach( $resultarray as $row )`, which runs the loop once for each element in the array, and the variable $row will contain the row.

Comment: Edited for clarity now @Tim, definitely a PHP question.

Comment: If you know the row number $new_array[0]["226"]["SupBusName"], if you don't know the row number then try $new_array[0][0]["SupBusName"].

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  Yes its PHP.  And 1 more thing as well. This query in question sorted through the results for a nearest location.  Probably not important. But like Charles, I thought Since their is only (1) $new_array, I created an array [$n], which is 1-100, I know the next array of [0] should be the 'MLocID' of which from there I should be able to refer to the actual 'Field Names'.  I thought by referring to my [$n] position, since I know that it is in order of how I want to display 5 results per page, that would make my life easier in trying to output the PHP variables.

Comment: I thought I could just $new_array[0][0]['SupBusName].  The second [0] part will always be [0] since their is only 1 of these.

Comment: Im sorry I worked on this for too long.  I just realized I can not refer to the [226] as [0].  Do I need to know that number or can I reference it as the first element of the [$n] array?  If I have that I know the fields in the [226] array.  I hope this makes sense its early. Or is it just easier to do a query for each of the 5 results with a for each statement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.
There was never a good reason to do this.

`$row = $resul->fetch_assoc(); $new_array[$n][$row['MLocID']] = $row;`

Instead I did this:

``
$row = $resul->fetch_array())
$new_array[$n] = $row;

``
And now I get this:

`[new_array] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 221 [MLocID] => 221 [1] => 2 [MemberID] => 2 [2] => Walmart 1`
And I can use both of these:

`echo $new_array[0][0]; echo $new_array[0]['MLocID'];`

Answer (score -1):

In your case you can access the array like this

```
foreach ($new_array as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as $_key => $_value) {
      
        $MLocID = $_value['MLocID'];
        $MemberID = $_value['MemberID'];
        $SupBusName = $_value['SupBusName'];

    }

  }
```